# Responsive Design but shows one column at right not at bottom

Tags: css, view, responsive

My Desktop view:
one-third two-third
X         XX

I want to get in Mobile devices :
X
XX

But I get

X  XX

XX is responsive.  But not showing at bottom.  It is showing at side and i don't know what to do?

My Css:
https://cncollege.net/wp-content/themes/cncollege/framework/css/shortcodes_ver-458.css

My first home page shows well.  But Other pages are not.

Comment: I don't see any media queries in your CSS. You need to set different values for .one-third and .two-thirds depending on the screen width. It would also be helpful if you picked out the CSS in question and posted it here so we don't have to look through your entire CSS file.

Comment: Thankyou.  Actually, my theme is http://mycollege.skat.tf/course/  There is no difference b/w the css files.  But in mobile view they are arranged one by one correctly.  But in my site, they are not arranged one by one.  And the 2-third appears to right with some space.  Also I am beginner. PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Some width for the content is set. I removed it.  That was the problem.